# Converting Flask WTForms with SQLAlchemy into a css form

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

So I am very new to python and Flask as well as SQLAlchemy but here is my problem. I want to transform the ugly wtforms from bootstrap into a nicer css form for login and signup. Here is my code.

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'I<+g/P2N$}0GXOf'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])
    remember = BooleanField('remember me')

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email(message='Invalid email'), Length(max=50)])
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])

@app.route("/home")
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data): 
                login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

        return '<h1>Invalid username or password</h1>'
        #return '<h1>' + form.username.data + ' ' + form.password.data + '</h1>'

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = RegisterForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return '<h1>New user has been created</h1>'
        # return '<h1>' + form.username.data + ' ' + form.email.data + ' ' + form.password.data + '</h1>'

    return render_template('signup.html', form=form)

@app.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html', name=current_user.username)

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('home'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,)
```

signup.html (working barebones but ugly)

```html
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}
Sign Up
{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('.static', filename='signin.css')}}">
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">

  <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="signup">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.username) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.email) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.password) }}
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->
{% endblock %}
```

signup.html (new one that I want to inherit the functionality of the other)

```html
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
      <button>create</button>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
```

I think that should be everything necessary, if there is a solution found for the signup I'm sure I can fix the login as well, let me know If any additional resources are required.

Comment: "Nicer" is subjective. Can you be explicit about what changes you'd like? Your "new" `signup.html` is very bare-bones as it stands.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, Its connected to my style sheet and looks how I want it to look but with the flask in the working HTML I can't change the css.

Comment: You can either override the bootstrap form classes (`form-group`, `form-control`, etc...) in your stylesheet if you want your changes broadly applied or add your own class to each element (e.g `{{ wtf.form_field(form.username, class="your-custom-class") }}`)

Comment: Thank you this works for me!